# Check if word can be built from array of chars in C

Tags: c, string

Hello i am creating hangman game and i have function which check if a word is guessed

Input parameters is secret "computer" for example and letters_guessed is which letters have been already guessed for example "fgtcsomputdser"

if computer can be built from these letters returns 1

my function wont work because if i try to run it for secret = computer and guessed = comp it returns me 1 word is guessed

```
int is_word_guessed(const char secret[], const char letters_guessed[]) {        
    int guessed;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(secret); i++) {
        guessed = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(letters_guessed); j++) {
            if(secret[i] == letters_guessed[j]) {
                guessed = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(guessed) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of guessed letters from the secret, and if that number is the same as the length of the secret, then the word was guessed

```
int is_word_guessed(const char secret[], const char letters_guessed[]) {        
  int guessed = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(secret); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen(letters_guessed); j++) {
      if(secret[i] == letters_guessed[j]) {
        guessed ++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if(guessed == strlen(secret)) return 1;
  else return 0;
}
```

Comment: why? it will break in the inner loop when it finds the first letter that matches, so increment at most once per character in secret

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for each letter in `secret` whether that letter is also in `letters_guessed[]`, but you do not retain the result for one letter when you proceed to check the next.  Therefore, the final result tells you only about the last letter checked, not the whole word.

There are various ways around this, but I suggest reversing the sense of your test: look for any letter in `secret` that is *not* in `letters_guessed`.  Return 0 as soon as you find such an unguessed letter, or return 1 if the loop terminates without finding one.